# Angularjs filter error from services data in the http url

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

i have a django method that calls a service as follows. Here is the method in the controller:

```
  $scope.showDegrees = function(degree){
            debugger
            $scope.DegreeCategory = degree.DegreeCategory;
            $scope.filterSub = degree.DegreeCategoryID;

            DegreesService.getDegrees(function(filterSub, data){
            $scope.degrees  = data;
            console.log(data);
      });

            $scope.display.academicdegrees = true;
          };
```

and in my services, i defined my factory as follows:

```
.factory('DegreesService',function($http) {
        return {
            getDegrees: function(degreecategoryid, callback) {
                //$http.get('/api/academicprogram/?format=json').success(callback);
                $http.get('/api/academicprogramlist2/'+degreecategoryid+'/').success(callback);
            }
        };
    })
```

When i am running it in chrome, the url is being passed wrong. It gives me the following error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/academicprogramlist2/function%20(filterSub,%20data)%7B%20%20%20%20$scope.degrees%20%20=%20data;console.log(data);%20%20%7D/ 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Looks like degreecategoryid is a function, and it's being used as a variable. Disclaimer: i have no AngularJS experience.

Comment: You passed only 1 param into getDegrees. The first param should be the categoryId. DegreesService.getDegrees(degree.DegreeCategoryID, function(filterSub, data) ...

Comment: hi your statement works. But i am not getting the json. Instead i get a value 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `DegreesService.getDegrees()` like this:

```
DegreesService.getDegrees(degree.DegreeCategoryID, function(response){...})
```

BTW, `$http.get()` returns a promise. **DO NOT** use callbacks if you have promises!

Comment: hi it is returning me the value 200 instead of the json when i am using this command   DegreesService.getDegrees(degree.DegreeCategoryID, function(filterSub, data) .. when i used your command, it gave me an error saying: "DegreesService.getDegrees(degree.DegreeCategoryID, function(filterSub, data)"  ..

Comment: log `response` to browser console to see it deeper. Go to angular docs to see what `$http.get()` promise resolves to on success.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get Search for HttpPromise